# Stripe, users can not download their invoice

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am working with Stripe Payment Gateway and everything is working so far, except the option, that my users can download their invoice on my website. It is possible to download an invoice inside the stripe dashboard but that is not what I need. After my users made a payment, they should be able to download their invoices to my system.

Currently I am working with stripe webhooks. A user makes a payment and the data is saved inside my database. This is how my code looks like:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("$stripe_secret_key_test");
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON:
$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($input);

// Update database with new billing entry
if ($event_json->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
    $invoice_id = $event_json->data->object->id;
    $customer = $event_json->data->object->customer;
    $date = $event_json->data->object->date;
    $price = $event_json->data->object->amount_paid;
    $user = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->metadata->userid;
    $stripe_sub_id = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->id;
    $plan_id = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->plan->id;
    $stamp_created = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->plan->created;
    $comments = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->plan->nickname;
    $period_start = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->period->start;
    $period_end = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->period->end;

    $content=array("invoice"=>$invoice_id,
        "user"=>$user,
        "stripe_cust_id"=>$customer,
        "stripe_sub_id"=>$stripe_sub_id,
        "idea_id"=>0,
        "billing_date"=>$date,
        "plan"=>$plan_id,
        "price"=>$price,
        "stamp_created"=>$stamp_created,
        "period_start"=>$period_start,
        "period_end"=>$period_end,
        "status"=>'paid',
        "printed"=>0);
    insertGWInfo('billing',$content);

    $content=array("user"=>$user,
        "trans_time"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        "ip"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        "trans_type"=>1,
        "cash_amount"=>$price,
        "comments"=>"Subscription for ".$comments."",
        "idea_id"=>0);
    insertGWInfo('user_accounting',$content);
}
```

Now I´ve created a table where I fetch those entries from my database and display them to my customer. I would like to have a button now with "Download Invoice" where my customers can download the subscription invoice which appears monthly.

Any idea how I can do this? I have the invoice_id but where do I get the URL to download an invoice? I wasn´t able to find anything inside the stripe docs. Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the JSON outcome for invoice.payment_suceeded:

```
"{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2018-02-28",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "in_00000000000000",
      "object": "invoice",
      "amount_due": 1000,
      "amount_paid": 1000,
      "amount_remaining": 0,
      "application_fee": null,
      "attempt_count": 1,
      "attempted": true,
      "billing": "charge_automatically",
      "charge": "_00000000000000",
      "closed": true,
      "currency": "eur",
      "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
      "date": 1526455801,
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "due_date": null,
      "ending_balance": 0,
      "forgiven": false,
      "lines": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "sub_Cs4DUPJKcAJ7cg",
            "object": "line_item",
            "amount": 1000,
            "currency": "eur",
            "description": "1 standard-inv × Standard Investor (at €10.00 / month)",
            "discountable": true,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "period": {
              "end": 1531726201,
              "start": 1529134201
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "3",
              "object": "plan",
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 1000,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1526375755,
              "currency": "eur",
              "interval": "month",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": "Standard Plan for Investors",
              "product": "prod_CrihTVfgRHgImD",
              "tiers": null,
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "proration": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": null,
            "subscription_item": "si_Cs4DrvYN2FlCbS",
            "type": "subscription"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1CSK5FDsOByhb3e8m8Z1BooY/lines"
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "next_payment_attempt": null,
      "number": "774C629-0001",
      "paid": true,
      "period_end": 1526455801,
      "period_start": 1526455801,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "starting_balance": 0,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "subscription": "sub_00000000000000",
      "subtotal": 1000,
      "tax": null,
      "tax_percent": null,
      "total": 1000,
      "webhooks_delivered_at": 1526455810
    }
  }
}"
```

Comment: If you have invoice id then you can retrieve it by using `\Stripe\Invoice::retrieve("in_InvoideId");`

Comment: Thank you that is what I thought too BUT how do I get the correct download link (url)? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: There must be an url also to download invoice with key `url`

Comment: I added the outcome of the json to my first post so that you can see what info I get. I am not sure how to get the correct download url. any idea?

Comment: If there is no any download option, then you can write content from retrieve invoice in file and download that file.

Comment: Any code snippet for me? I do not exactly know what you mean and how I can do that?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stripe does not support downloading the invoice as a PDF at the moment via the API and it is only available in the dashboard instead.

For now, the best solution is to build your own invoice receipt/pdf instead. You can retrieve the [Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object) object via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice) which tells you what the invoice is for: period, amount, when it was paid, what's in that invoice, etc. And you can then generate your own receipt for your customers on your end.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to know. Hope Stripe will offer this feature in the near future.

Answer (score 39):

Stripe DOES support this now. The PDF link is available by listing the invoices via the API and accessing the `invoice_pdf` attribute of an invoice.

Here's how you can get an array of invoices with their PDF links:

```
const invoicesResponse = await stripe.invoices.list({ customer: customerStripeId });
const invoices = invoicesResponse.map(invoice => ({
    invoiceId: invoice['id'],
    pdf: invoice['invoice_pdf'],
  }));
return invoices;
```

Here's the API docs:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-invoice_pdf Thanks @avelis for the suggestion.

Comment: A link to the API docs showing the invoice PDF response attribute. https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-invoice_pdf

Comment: Is this possible with the receipt ? The difference is that the receipt is a paid invoice.

Answer (score 5):

it is posible :)  works like a charm with the Python API.

```
import stripe
import requests

stripe_keys = {'secret_key': 'XXXxxxx','publishable_key': 'XXXxxxx'}
stripe.api_key = stripe_keys['secret_key']

stripe_subscription_id = 'XXXXXXX'
invoices = stripe.Invoice.list(subscription=stripe_subscription_id)
for inv in invoices:
    pdf          = inv.invoice_pdf
    invoice_file = requests.get(pdf)
    open('C://User//XXXXX//Desktop//invoice.pdf', 'wb').write(invoice_file.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way now. Following are the steps I follow to use Stripe's default method to download the invoice pdf.

1. Find the customer for which I want to download the invoice in pdf format

   ```
   const findCustomerByEmail = async (email) => {
     try {
       const customer = await stripe.customers.list({
         email,
         limit: 1,
       });
       if (customer.data.length !== 0) {
         return customer.data[0].id;
       }
     } catch (e) {
       return (e);
     }
   };
   ```
2. Now that I have the customer, I then find all the invoices of the user:

   ```
    exports.getInvoices = async (req, res, next) => {
         const cusStripeId = await findCustomerByEmail(req.user.email);

         const invoices = await stripe.invoices.list({
           limit: 3000,
           customer: cusStripeId,

         });
         res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(invoices);
    };
   ```
3. Now I have a list of the invoices for this user. I can traverse through all the invoices.

> invoices.data[0].invoice_pdf

**invoices** object is an array, and the **data[0].invoice_pdf** has a link that will download pdf. As an alternative we can also see the invoice as an html page without the need to download it, as follows.

> invoices.data[0].hosted_invoice_url